# ess-mode library name auto-complete

Tags: ess, r

I've been looking around for a solution to get company-mode to auto-complete R library names in ess-mode. The R libraries are stored in folders with the same name, wouldn't it be just the case of picking candidates from a directory tree? Does anyone know how to make ess-mode auto-compelte library names?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've been reading a bit about Emacs Lisp and came up with the following solution. This is my very first Lisp function and as such I am not sure whether I've covered all pitfalls. It requires running iESS.

```
;; insert R library line using helm
(defun helm-ess-R-library-name-insert ()
  "Insert 'library(_library-name_)'."
  (interactive)
  (let
      ((lib-name (helm :sources (helm-build-in-buffer-source "R-library"
                  :data (ess-get-words-from-vector
                     "print(.packages(T), max=1e6)\n"))
               :buffer "*R library*")))
    (if (not (string= lib-name nil))
       (if (string= (message "%s" major-mode) "ess-mode")
          (insert (format "library(%s)\n" lib-name))
         (ess-eval-linewise (format "library('%s')\n" lib-name))))))
;; re-map the key from ess-load-library
(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-e l") 'helm-ess-R-library-name-insert)
```